# Events between two dates using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Actually i wanted to ask a simple question!
I have a table named as **events** with major fields as (**'name','creation_date','ending_date'**).
Now what i want to do is to, get all the events between today date and the expiry date.
Can anyone please help me that how i can sort this out.

Please tell me how i can get all the events between today date and expiry date in secure way.

Comment: what do you mean by `secure way` ?

Comment: what should be in between today's date and expiry date? the `creation_date` or `ending_date`?

Comment: There would be some events, For example i am creating an event and i have set an expiry date of that event, Then it would lie between today date and expiry date. If it is below your today date, it means date passes away and event is expired now.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT * FROM events WHERE CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN creation_date AND ending_date
```

Comment: `creation_date` should be changed to `NOW()`

Comment: Careful!  If 'ending_date' or `CURRENT_DATE` aren't simply dates, but instead have time fields in them, you're going to want   ...  `CURRENT_DATE >= creation_date AND CURRENT_DATE < ending_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY`

Comment: @SableFoste: The question is a bit ambiguous, so it is not entirely clear what the OP wants; but in any event [`CURRENT_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date) *is* the date part of `NOW()`.

Comment: @OllieJones: Or perhaps `NOW() BETWEEN ...`?  The question is a bit ambiguous: I had mostly intended to illustrate use of the [`BETWEEN ... AND ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator.

Comment: The problem with BETWEEN for date/time values is this: '2012-09-07 14:30' is not `BETWEEN '2012-09-06' AND '2012-09-07'`. It is `< '2012-09-07' + INTERVAL 1 DAY`. In my experience using `BETWEEN` for date ranges often leaves out items on the last day of the range.  Hence my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE (ending_date - NOW() ) <0 ;
```